# What's the meaning of "if anything else"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, colloquialisms

I don't seem to understand the exact meaning of "if anything else" in the beginning portion of the sentence below. I think I could use your help to understand what it actually means.

> **If anything else**, the government's job is to protect the safety and health of our citizens.

Comment: I do not think the "else" belong there. The idiomatic expression is _If anything_ https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22if+anything%22

Comment: As such it is a duplicate: [Meaning of if anything](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70359/meaning-of-if-anything)

Comment: This looks like the author mixed up two expressions: _if anything_ and _if nothing else_. I wouldn't be surprised if it catches on as yet another sentence that does anything but express the speaker's actual intention, like "I could care less" :(

Answer (score 2):

The writer has been too liberal in his/her idiomatic usage. (as @Oerkelens states, mixed up)

> If anything ,the government's job is to protect the safety and health of our citizens.

Reference: [If anything](http://www.manilatimes.net/what-does-the-idiomatic-expression-if-anything-mean/56745/), [If at all](http://josecarilloforum.com/forum/index.php?topic=6095.0)

The  closest meaning I can think of for it is “if at all”.

```
 The idiom “if anything” is used to convey the sense that someone or something is 
 different when the speaker isn’t absolutely sure if there really is any change or 
 difference.
```

Comment: I believe this was already all covered in the comments. Also it is a duplicate so already has an answer

Answer (score 1):

If the object of the sentence is to define the bare minimum of the duties of a government, one could write:
"If nothing else, it is the government's job to protect the safety and health of its citizens."